# tikz - custom page dimensions, background image & centered text

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, dimensions

I have an image (983x983 pixels) that I want to use as the background of my standalone document. I then want to add text on top of it, centered.
When I do

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=983pt, height=983pt]{background.png}};
        \node at (100pt,100pt) {Content here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The image fits within the page perfectly, but the text is obviously not centered. When I do

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=983pt, height=983pt]{background.png}};
        \node at (491.5pt,491.5pt) {Content here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The image is not fitting in the page anymore and the text is at the top right corner (?)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if the text should be centred, also place it at (0,0)?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm so stupid, I thought (0, 0) was the top-left corner... thank you!

Comment: I agree with samcarter, the node with the image will (in this case) have (0,0) at the center of the image. So if you name the node, say `\node[...] (IMG) at ...`, then you can use `\node at (IMG) {content here};` to add it in the center in relation to IMG (you might need `(IMG.center)`. Untested.

Comment: @ituriel that is what `anchor=...` is for, the default is `center` I assume.

Comment: @daleif Would you like to answer?

Comment: @daleif is there a way I can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the default settings in TikZ is to our advantage.

When you do

```
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {...};
```

The contents will be placed with its vertical and horisontal center at `(0,0)` (you can use, say, `anchor=...` to change how the contents is placed in relation to the point.

Thus it is enough to just use

```
\node at (0,0) {some contents};
```

And it will be centered in relation to the image.

In general it is useful to name nodes, then we can refer to various properties of that name

```
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (IMG) at (0,0) {...};
\node at (IMG.center) {some contents};
```

Edit: Even if `anchor=...` is set to say `west`, `(IMG)` and `(IMG.center)` is still the vertical and horisontal center of that node.

This feature is super useful if, say you have a circular image (properly cropped) and you'd like to add a circular slightly bigger background behind it.

```
 \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2cm);
 \node[...] at (0,0) {image};
```

and you are done.